# Ubuntu + Windows Fails

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I want to put windows and Ubuntu together in one pc (seems possible xD).

I reduce my hard drive to 150GB and install Ubuntu 14.04 on that. All easily. He installed all well and I restart it. Then immediately suggests a update, which I installed also. Another reboot and then it happens. The boot manager grub works and it also starts, but will not display, but it shows an black screen or there is the following error message:

```
[4.498559] sd 0: 0: 0: 0: [sdg] No caching mode page found
[4.498600] sd 0: 0: 0: 0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through
[12.205496] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Broken pipe
```

I installed then Ubuntu [13.10](/questions/tagged/13.10), [14.04](/questions/tagged/14.04) and [14.10](/questions/tagged/14.10) with the same problem:
Either black screen or remains stuck at the points of loading. I have checked my hard disk to the cluster error and also defragmented. It is not on the hard disk and the CD-ROM drive that burns the CD it is also not, because I have also used other CD burner with the same problem.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please follow the advice in the above link and report back @Fabby if something doesn't work there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered through trial and error that though probably greater than 80% of PCs are Linux compatible, a disturbing percentage simply are not.  This is why when asked for advice I always advise putting a PC through its paces either with an Ubuntu boot CD/DVD, or alternately a Ubuntu boot flash drive.  I prefer the latter for reasons explained in my bio here.

In any case though I'm not saying your computer simply will not work with Ubuntu, there may be a fix, you should accept the possibility that either it isn't compatible or that the solution may be prohibitively complicated.

Please update your query with a few stats about the computer, particularly the brand and model number so that others can attempt to determine if it is one of the troubled ones.